# How can I get the selected item in an edit-text and show that item within a rectangle box with cross symbol

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am developing a messaging app so for that, I want to show the selected contacts in Edit-Text as in the below image. See in the below image upper edit-text shows the contact name within a small rectangle box with the cross symbol to remove it.

How can I make that design, any suggestion or trick will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is possible by using Google's FlexBoxLayout which was recently launched by google for Android platform.

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Steps to do :

1) Add Flexbox dependency in gradle.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.1'
}
```

2) Take a recyclerview and design its item as you want to show and make a recycler Adapter.

3) Set layoutmanager of recyclerview with FlexboxLayoutManager.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(demoAdapter);
```

And then you are good to go. :) Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks for the lead Mr.SK